# How to pull in files with synchronize-module via rsync/ssh?

Tags: ansible, rsync

I'm trying to implement a task using the [synchronize-module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html), as suggested in [this question](/questions/25505146/)'s answers. The goal is to have a multitude of hosts pull things from a central location using `rsync` over `ssh`.

The source-server (`wallaby`) is *not* part of the inventory. Here is the task:

```
- name: Populate directory
  synchronize:
    dest: "/local/path"
    src: "wallaby:/remote/path"
    mode: pull
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Unfortunately, however I phrase the `src` argument, the local path to the playbook is prepended to it resulting in an rsync command line like
`/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates ... /home/mi/A/playbooks/wallaby:/remote/path /local/path`, which, of course, completely breaks rsync.

Note, that the delegated-to host performing the rsync does not even have `/home/mi/A/playbooks/` on it, so this is, obviously, a bug in the module. How do I work around it?..

Comment: `rsync://wallaby/remote/path`

Comment: That requires `wallaby` to run rsync-daemon, does not it?